5 GHz WiFi is not working on Debian 12 , Hostapd , firmware-atheros , Kernel Info: Debian GNU/Linux 12.5 (Kernel:6.1.0-18-amd64 x86_64)
I have a debian 9 router that supports both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. As debian 9 lost its life time I decided to upgrade my router software to debian 12 and after upgrading 2.4 GHz is working fine but 5 GHz is not working.
logs ====>
    1712216493.716925: 1712216493.716931: wlp3s0: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
1712216493.717027: Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
1712216493.717075: wlp3s0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
1712216493.717127: wlp3s0: AP-DISABLED 
1712216493.717169: wlp3s0: Unable to setup interface.
1712216493.717212: wlp3s0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
1712216493.717527: wlp3s0: AP-DISABLED 
1712216493.717583: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
1712216493.717625: hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp3s0 wasn't started
1712216493.717653: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
1712216513.768482: wlp3s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
1712216513.771155: ACS: Automatic channel selection started, this may take a bit
1712216513.771219: ACS: No available channels found
1712216513.771289: 1712216513.771293: wlp3s0: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (0) or frequency (0) (secondary_channel=0) not found from the channel list of the current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a

And also iw list command shows all the 5ghz channel are marked as NO IR.
Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)

But debian 9 still working just fine. FYI, I am using firmware-atheros version 20230625-2 and hostapd to set up the Wifi
Also dmesg shows a error message which is the following,
[ 3071.247514] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pdev param 0 not supported by firmware


Even if that's not a complete fix, you could try disabling ACS and choosing yourself your channel. This won't exercise the same driver path and might work. (I know about this because I had a driver regression for unrelated rt2800usb driver which made ACS fail)

yes . I tried that as well , but no luck . same error

Did you try the fix that I suggested, did it work for you?

you didn't get my problem. It has nothing to do with WPA @NaveedAhmed

Finally I was able to fix the issue.
The problem was with the newer hostapd ( 2:2.10-12) of debian 12 bookworm repo. I had to revert back to the old hostapd (2:2.4-1+deb9u9) of debian 9  to make the 5 Ghz work in debian 12.

This could happen after the upgrade, I think you need to disable WPA2/WPA3 in Router and use WPA1/WPA2 instead for the 5GHz. Let us know it it helps.

no, that does absolutely not normally happen after an upgrade! And none of the log entries suggest Md. even came to the point where they would authenticate, so unless there's some very clear reason to assume that's related, please do not suggest people downgrade the security of their wifi. If there is a good reason, your answer should ideally explain it!

I have rephrased my statement that might want you to take back your downvote.

Then this should really just have been a comment, not an answer. Your recommendation seems interesting, why would downgrading WPA generation help the fact that no channel can be chosen?

I would be glad to answer you if you add a new question instead of asking it in an existing thread. ;)

I'm sorry, I'm not jumping through that hoop for you: an answer should explain, at least roughly, what it does, and why. Especially if it recommends a downgrade of a security mechanism that doesn't stand in direct relation to the problem.
